# Unable to make a simple grid layout with 4 buttons in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.label import Label  
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout  
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout    
class Grid(GridLayout):
    pass
class UcoeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()
UcoeApp().run()
```

ucoe.kv file is as follows:

```
<Grid>:
GridLayout:
    cols:2
    row_force_default:True
    row_default_height:40

Button:
    text:"hello1"
    size_hint_x:None
    width=100
Button:
    text:"world1"


Button:
    text:"hello2"
    size_hint_x:None
    width:100
Button:
    text:"world2"
```

but i am getting the error as follows:
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1440, in parse_level
     'Invalid data after declaration')
 kivy.lang.ParserException: Parser: File "/home/dimple/ucoe.kv", line 4:
 ...
       2:    GridLayout:
       3:        cols:2

> > 4:   row_force_default:True
> >            5:   row_default_height:40
> >            6:
> >      ...
> >      Invalid data after declaration
> >     Please help ,i am a newbie to kivy.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of bug in yr code.

- import button
- in .kv under button width=100 (wrong)
- remove GridLayout in .kv it is not required.

Below is the updated and running code.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.label import Label  
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout  
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout    
class Grid(GridLayout):
    pass
class UcoeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()
UcoeApp().run()
```

ucoe.kv file =>

```
<Grid>:
    cols:2
    row_force_default:True
    row_default_height:40
    Button:
        text:"hello1"
        size_hint_x:None
        width:100
    Button:
        text:"world1"
    Button:
        text:"hello2"
        size_hint_x:None
        width:100
    Button:
        text:"world2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit as you see fit.

main.py

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout    
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Grid(GridLayout):
    pass


presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class UcoeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()


UcoeApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<Grid@GridLayout>:
    cols:2
    Button:
        text:"hello1"
        size: self.size
    Button:
        text:"world1"
        size: self.size
    Button:
        text:"hello2"
        size: self.size
    Button:
        text:"world2"
        size: self.size
```